# Preventing the join() command from adding extra space

Tags: whitespace, join

I am trying to use the `join` command to join multiple strings. The `join` command seems to add one character of space in between each of the strings. But I don't want any space added.

As an example, I'm working on a function that finds the associated .pdf file of a .tex file. So if I'm editing the file */home/user/paper.tex*, I would like to create the string */home/user/paper.pdf*. My attempt is

```
join([expand('%:p:r'), '.pdf'])
```

which returns `/home/user/paper .pdf`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`:help join()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#join%28%29):

```
join({list} [, {sep}])

            [..]

            When {sep} is specified it is put in between the items.  If
            {sep} is omitted a single space is used.

            [..]
```

So the solution is to add an empty string in the second `sep` parameter:

```
:echo join([expand('%:p:r'), '.pdf'])
/usr/share/vim/vim81/doc/eval .pdf

:echo join([expand('%:p:r'), '.pdf'], '')
/usr/share/vim/vim81/doc/eval.pdf
```

In this case you don't really need to use `join()` by the way, and could just use:

```
:echo expand('%:p:r') . '.pdf'
```

Comment: Thanks. So in your last command, you have a period between the strings. I've seen a period used like that before, but I don't understand, what does it do?

Comment: See `:help expression-syntax` .  In this context '.' is string concatenation.

Comment: I want to make note that I didn't realize that `:help join` and `:help join()` bring you to different parts of the help section.